# Attempt to use @INC and call function on demand

Tags: perl

I am trying to learn how to use a .pm file. I created 2 files:

- MyScript.pl

  ```
    use strict;
    BEGIN {
      unshift(@INC,"./firstdir");
      }
    my @list = qw (J u s t ~ A n o t h e r ~ P e r l ~ H a c k e r !);

   use seconddir::MyModule qw(func1) ;

   print func1(@list),"\n";     #line 21
   print MyModule::func2(@list),"\n";
  ```
- MyModule.pm

  ```
   package MyModule; 

   use strict;
   use Exporter;
   use vars qw($VERSION @ISA @EXPORT @EXPORT_OK %EXPORT_TAGS);

   $VERSION     = 1.00;
   @ISA         = qw(Exporter); 
   @EXPORT      = ();   
   @EXPORT_OK   = qw(func1 func2); 
   %EXPORT_TAGS = ( DEFAULT => [qw(&func1)],
           Both    => [qw(&func1 &func2)]);

   sub func1  { return reverse @_  }
   sub func2  { return map{ uc }@_ }

    1;
  ```

the structure of the directories is as following:

```
 ---------------         ------------     ---------------
 | firstdir ---|------> |seconddir--|-> | MyModule.pm |
 | MyScript.pl |         ------------    ---------------
  ---------------
```

note: firstdir and seconddir are directories
when I run the command `Perl MyScript.pl` I receive the following error:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::func1 called at MyScript.pl line 21
```

can you help me figure out what is wrong please?

Comment: Tip: `BEGIN { unshift(@INC,"./firstdir"); }` is better written as `use lib 'firstdir';`. Not only is it short, it's better since it'll also include any build-specific subdirectories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your package name is wrong, it should be:

```
package seconddir::MyModule
```

Then you should call `func2` with:

```
print seconddir::MyModule::func2(@list),"\n";
```

or by exporting it, as with `func1`.

Comment: i don't have problems with func2 , only with func1.  i am trying exporting it and them using it as any other function in the pl file, that's how it suppose to work, doesn't it?

Comment: Alternatively, don't put MyModule in a directory.

Comment: @Vera, exporting only works if the package name in your module and the package name in your `use` are the same.

Answer (score 1):

`func1` should be in the  `@EXPORT` array in the module MyModule.pm if you want to call it directly as `func1` in your main script.

Answer (score 0):

```
@EXPORT = qw(func1 func2);
```

You need to add the names of the symbols in the `@EXPORT` array in order to access them from you script.

Comment: That exports them by default, they're already added to `@EXPORT_OK` so he can request them exported as he is with `use seconddir::MyModule qw(func1);`

Comment: I don't want to export them by default, i an trying to export func1 by demand, and it's not working.

Comment: maybe i'm missing something, when i am exporting something it's gives direct excess to this function, doesn't it?